# Could not create PTY IntelliJ error and winpty-agent.exe runs over and over when IDE is open

Tags: windows, svn, intellij-idea

I get the following error in IntelliJ when I am trying to check out in svn. Moreover, when I open IDE the `winpty-agent.exe` runs over and over again.

```
   could not create PTY
```

My OS: Win7 64bit

Intellij version: 15.0